# Interpretation of output generated by PROCESS macro in SPSS for model with two moderators

Tags: multiple-regression, spss, interpretation

I used the PROCESS macro for SPSS from hayes to regress a model where det_mean is the indepedent variable and y_tot the depending variable. I'm testing if this relation is moderated by two variables wix_tot and dx_tot

I have trouble interpreting the output generated by the macro. I've included the information below.

The model is significant according to the model summary
R-Square = 2825, F(5,83) = 6,5375, p<.001

The relation between det_mean and tprmean is also significant (coeff =,5656; p<.001) 
but then im getting lost, i think i have one significant interaction effect and one not significant.

Can somebody help me explaining how to interpretate the coefficients and the relation between the interaction

```
Run MATRIX procedure:

**************** PROCESS Procedure for SPSS Release 2.041 ****************

        Written by Andrew F. Hayes, Ph.D.   http://www.afhayes.com

**************************************************************************
Model = 2
    Y = tprmean
    X = det_mean
    M = waxmean
    W = dxmean

Sample size
         89

**************************************************************************
Outcome: tprmean

Model Summary
          R       R-sq          F        df1        df2          p
      ,5316      ,2825     6,5375     5,0000    83,0000      ,0000

Model
              coeff         se          t          p       LLCI       ULCI
constant     3,3301      ,0510    65,2746      ,0000     3,2286     3,4316
waxmean       ,0425      ,0751      ,5661      ,5729     -,1069      ,1919
det_mean      ,5656      ,1394     4,0575      ,0001      ,2883      ,8429
int_1         ,5963      ,2010     2,9669      ,0039      ,1965      ,9960
dxmean        ,0075      ,0781      ,0954      ,9242     -,1479      ,1629
int_2        -,1049      ,1967     -,5331      ,5954     -,4962      ,2864

Interactions:

 int_1    det_mean    X     waxmean
 int_2    det_mean    X     dxmean

R-square increase due to interaction(s):
         R2-chng          F        df1        df2          p
int_1      ,0761     8,8022     1,0000    83,0000      ,0039
int_2      ,0025      ,2842     1,0000    83,0000      ,5954
Both       ,0764     4,4200     2,0000    83,0000      ,0150

*************************************************************************

Conditional effect of X on Y at values of the moderator(s)
     dxmean    waxmean     Effect         se          t          p       LLCI       ULCI
     -,7296     -,7657      ,1856      ,2579      ,7195      ,4738     -,3274      ,6985
     -,7296      ,0000      ,6421      ,2145     2,9935      ,0036      ,2155     1,0688
     -,7296      ,7657     1,0987      ,2700     4,0698      ,0001      ,5617     1,6357
      ,0000     -,7657      ,1090      ,2251      ,4844      ,6294     -,3387      ,5568
      ,0000      ,0000      ,5656      ,1394     4,0575      ,0001      ,2883      ,8429
      ,0000      ,7657     1,0222      ,1886     5,4207      ,0000      ,6471     1,3972
      ,7296     -,7657      ,0325      ,2757      ,1179      ,9064     -,5159      ,5810
      ,7296      ,0000      ,4891      ,1845     2,6503      ,0096      ,1220      ,8561
      ,7296      ,7657      ,9457      ,1986     4,7618      ,0000      ,5507     1,3406

Values for quantitative moderators are the mean and plus/minus one SD from mean.
Values for dichotomous moderators are the two values of the moderator.

**************************************************************************

Data for visualizing conditional effect of X of Y
   det_mean     dxmean    waxmean       yhat
     -,3821     -,7296     -,7657     3,2212
      ,0000     -,7296     -,7657     3,2921
      ,3821     -,7296     -,7657     3,3630
     -,3821     -,7296      ,0000     3,0793
      ,0000     -,7296      ,0000     3,3247
      ,3821     -,7296      ,0000     3,5700
     -,3821     -,7296      ,7657     2,9374
      ,0000     -,7296      ,7657     3,3572
      ,3821     -,7296      ,7657     3,7770
     -,3821      ,0000     -,7657     3,2559
      ,0000      ,0000     -,7657     3,2976
      ,3821      ,0000     -,7657     3,3392
     -,3821      ,0000      ,0000     3,1140
      ,0000      ,0000      ,0000     3,3301
      ,3821      ,0000      ,0000     3,5462
     -,3821      ,0000      ,7657     2,9721
      ,0000      ,0000      ,7657     3,3627
      ,3821      ,0000      ,7657     3,7532
     -,3821      ,7296     -,7657     3,2906
      ,0000      ,7296     -,7657     3,3030
      ,3821      ,7296     -,7657     3,3154
     -,3821      ,7296      ,0000     3,1487
      ,0000      ,7296      ,0000     3,3355
      ,3821      ,7296      ,0000     3,5224
     -,3821      ,7296      ,7657     3,0068
      ,0000      ,7296      ,7657     3,3681
      ,3821      ,7296      ,7657     3,7294

******************** ANALYSIS NOTES AND WARNINGS *************************

Level of confidence for all confidence intervals in output:
    95,00

NOTE: The following variables were mean centered prior to analysis:
 det_mean waxmean  dxmean

------ END MATRIX -----
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the p-value of `int_1` and `int_2`. The moderator `dxmean` does not moderate the relationship. Also notice that zero falls within the LLCI and ULCI values, suggesting that it is not significant.